# Cake PHP 2 save data via model in Event Listener

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.4

I've got an event listener in my project's `Lib/Event` directory and a model called `QueueManagerJob`.

My application dispatches an event at some point and I'd like to save an entry into my database through my model. When my event is dispatched, it runs a `store` method in the listener and it's here where I'm referencing my model and am trying to save it.

I've pulled the model in via the `$uses` array but I'm getting the following error:

> Call to a member function set() on null

```php
<?php

App::uses('CakeEventListener', 'Event', 'CakeLog');

class DispatchJobListener implements CakeEventListener {
    public $uses = array('QueueManagerJob');

    public function implementedEvents() {
        return array(
            'QueueManagerModule.QueueManagerJob.dispatchJob' => 'store'
        );
    }

    /**
    * Store the data
    */
    public function store($event) {
        $event->stopPropagation();

        $job = [
            'queue' => 'default',
            'payload' => json_encode([]),
            'attempts' => 0,
            'reserved_at' => null,
            'available_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ];

        $this->QueueManagerJob->set($job);

        // invalid
        if (!$this->QueueManagerJob->validates()) {
            // $this->QueueManagerJob->validationErrors;
            // ...
        }

        // save the job
        $this->QueueManagerJob->save($job);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class only implements an interface, there is no further logic that would make use of the `$uses` property.

The `$uses` property is only recognized out of the box by controllers, if you need to load models in other places, then you have to use `ClassRegistry::init()`, like:

```php
App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');

// ...

$QueueManagerJob = ClassRegistry::init('QueueManagerJob');
```

Also note that `App::uses()` only accepts two arguments, the class name and the package name, the third argument in your example won't do anything!